# Function to calculate the day number of the week from the date/time string in R

Tags: r

I have one function given below:## function to calculate the day number of the week from the date/time string

```
getDayOfWeek <- function(vector) {
    split1 <- strsplit(paste(vector), " ")
    dateIs <- as.POSIXlt(split1[[1]][1])
    print (dateIs$wday)
 }
```

However this function is written based on `2016-06-12 11:23:25.680Z` format but my data is in `%m%d%y %h%m`. How can i change the format of original datetime that is being used in function. I want to apply this function to my data frame in order to get name of week based on time in additional column.

I am using

```
taxidata$weekday <-sapply(taxidata$tpep_pickup_datetime, FUN=getDayOfWeek)
```

i am getting following error:

> Error in as.POSIXlt.character(split1[[1]][1]) :    character string is
>   not in a standard unambiguous format

I also used:

```
taxidata$dayofweek <- weekdays(as.Date.POSIXct(taxidata$tpep_pickup_datetime, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))
head(taxidata, n =3)
```

but this function is giving me only Thursday for all data point.

Answer (score 0):

Given e.g.

```
x <- "2016-06-12 11:23:25.680Z"
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# [1] "2016-06-12 11:23:25 CEST"
```

or

```
x <- "061216 1123"
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%m%d%y %H%M")
# [1] "2016-06-12 11:23:00 CEST"
```

`?strptime` tells you

> %u: Weekday as a decimal number (1–7, Monday is 1)

So you could do

```
format(as.POSIXct(x, format = "%m%d%y %H%M"), "%u")
# [1] "7"
```

> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

means that e.g. `2016-06-12` could be interpreted as 12th June or 6th December. You should specify the format.

Comment: VendorID tpep_pickup_datetime tpep_dropoff_datetime
2 1/15/2015 19:05 1/15/2015 19:23
1 1/10/2015 20:33 1/10/2015 20:53
1 1/10/2015 20:33 1/10/2015 20:43
1 1/10/2015 20:33 1/10/2015 20:35
1 1/10/2015 20:33 1/10/2015 20:52
 Above is part of my dataset and i am trying to use                                  > getDayOfWeek <- function(vector) {
+   split1 <- strsplit(paste(vector), " ")
+   format(taxidata,format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
+   dateIs <- as.POSIXlt(split1[[1]][1])
+   print (dateIs$wday)
+ }
> taxidata$weekday <-sapply(taxidata$tpep_pickup_datetime,FUN=getDayOfWeek)

Comment: Have you tried 
x <-c("2016-06-28 00:22:30", "2016-06-29 01:15:50", "2016-06-30 02:09:10", 
"2016-07-01 03:02:30", "2016-07-02 03:55:50", "2016-07-03 04:49:10", 
"2016-07-04 05:42:30", "2016-07-05 06:35:50", "2016-07-06 07:29:10", 
"2016-07-07 08:22:30", "2016-07-08 09:15:50", "2016-07-09 10:09:10", 
"2016-07-10 11:02:30", "2016-07-11 11:55:50", "2016-07-12 12:49:10", 
"2016-07-13 13:42:30", "2016-07-14 14:35:50", "2016-07-15 15:29:10", 
"2016-07-16 16:22:30", "2016-07-17 17:15:50", "2016-07-18 18:09:10") z <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") format(z, "%u")
 ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use lubridate: `t <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2016-06-12 11:23:25.680Z")` with
`lubridate::wday(t, label = F, abbr = F)` (=1) or
`lubridate::wday(t, label = T, abbr = T)` (=Sun).

Comment: Thanks guys. I figured using as.Date(jan2015$tpep_pickup_datetime) that changed my date time format as per my function.